# Error creating contracts on Ethereum wallet. Need help

Tags: tokens, erc-20, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapps

I am trying to create an ERC20 token off of ethereum, but when I put the code in the editor in the ethereum wallet, I get a weird error. It says:

```
 "throw" is deprecated in favour of "revert()", "require()" and "assert()".
    if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;
                                        ^---^
```

(from [Ethereum Blog](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/12/03/how-to-build-your-own-cryptocurrency/))
([Source Code](http://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/?gist=21935dc37c5bfbe92e5a))
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried comiling with a different IDE (Like Remix at http://remix.ethereum.org/ ) ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states clearly

> throw has been deprecated

Use

```
require( balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value)
```

You can find a detailed description in this [article](https://media.consensys.net/when-to-use-revert-assert-and-require-in-solidity-61fb2c0e5a57).

revert() and require() both refund any left over gas however assert() consumes all the gas provided.

> The require function should be used to ensure valid conditions, such
>   as inputs, or contract state variables are met, or to validate return
>   values from calls to external contracts. If used properly, analysis
>   tools can evaluate your contract to identify the conditions and
>   function calls which will reach a failing assert. Properly functioning
>   code should never reach a failing assert statement; if this happens
>   there is a bug in your contract which you should fix

.